# Qt QTableView - 'Nothing selected' signal

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to enable/disable a QPushButton if anything in my QTableView is selected/unselected. If something's selected, the button should be enabled. If nothing is, it should be disabled. How can I do this? I'm trying with a QItemSelectionModel, but I don't succeed (apparently neither the row or column number changes if I don't click into another cell):

```
connect(selection, &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,[=]() {

        int integ;
        integ = selection->currentIndex().row();


        QMessageBox * message = new QMessageBox;
        message->setText("lol" + QString::number(integ) );
        message->exec();


        if((selection->currentIndex().column() >= 0 && selection->currentIndex().column() < 6 )) {
            payinButton->setEnabled(true);
        } else {
        payinButton->setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried calling payinButton->setEnabled(selection->hasSelection()) ?

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Add it as an answer, I'll choose that as a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you are looking for is:

```
payinButton->setEnabled(selection->hasSelection());
```